# What is the best way to keep track of images uploaded by an user using PHP

Tags: php

I am planning to do a photo album website, So each user may upload as many number of images. What is the best way to keep track of images for an individual user. What should be the server configuration to handle this part.

-Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of images, you will probably want to store them on a static domain. Then, have a table in whatever database you are using to store the paths to each of the images for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Well like many design topics there are lots of different ways to go about it. Two ways that come to mind right now are as follows.

1. you could simply have a directory created on the server for each user and then have the images each use uploads saved into that directory. Ofcourse you'd want to make sure they didn't over write any existing images with images of the same name. You could do this by warning them about conflicting names or by adding some sort of noce string (like a time stamp) to the end of of the file name. This is a pretty straight forward solution and means that you can login to your server and see all the images each user has uploaded right there for you to do anything you like with.
2. Another idea would be to save the images in a database. This can be done by serializing the images to a string and storing it in a database. This is nice becaues it means you don't have to worry about handling directories and duplicate file names. You will have to deserialize each image when you want to display it which will put your DB under load so for a very high traffic volume site this might not really be the way to go.

There are ofcourse combinations of these ideas and many others. It really comes down to working out which solution best fits your exact needs.